# Label inside gridview is not showing any value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

`Label4` inside gridview is not displaying textbox value while `Label5` outside gridview is showing the textbox value. `Label4` Value is blank. I want that the label i.e `Label4` should display `Label5.Text`.

```
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Place Details">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("phno") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </b> 
                    </td>                                     
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zone") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What makes you think that `Label4` shows `Label5.Text`?

Comment: Label address = (Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("Label4");
            Label5.Text = txtDestination.Text;
            address.Text = Label5.Text;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label value is not showing which is inside gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913482/label-value-is-not-showing-which-is-inside-gridview)

Comment: As asked in your other question, there is no mention as to WHERE and WHEN you try and execute that code.

Comment: Label address = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label4");
            Label5.Text = txtDestination.Text;
            address.Text = Label5.Text;

Comment: Does Label5 display correct text? Where have you written this code? Can you post in in the question?

Comment: Yes Label5 is showing correct Text.

Answer (score 1):

Using Gridview Row Databound bind value of label4

```
Label Label4 = (Label)e.row.findcontrol("Label4");

Label4.text = (Your Value assign here)
```

so display your value

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue which disappeared when I commented out everything inside my GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) method. I was adding a tooltip to all cells in the row which I think overwritten it.

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    //    var id = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

    //if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    //{
}
```